# Como filtrar campos en tabla de data studio con ultima modificación de fecha

Tags: sql

En esta tabla tengo el mismo id repetido 2 veces, pero deseo poder filtrarlos por la última modificación de fecha del atributo modifiedDate_time, ósea que se muestre solo las últimas modificaciones de la fecha sin repetir el campo, no encontré mucha información, por eso recurro aquí, también me comentaron que podría usar MAX, pero no me funciono. Desde ya muchas gracias, por cierto, esto es en Data Studio, LookerStudio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrias probar:

```
SELECT * FROM TuTabla WHERE modifiedDate_time = (SELECT MAX(modifiedDate_time) from TuTabla)
```

En ves de utilizar el MAX a secas en tu WHERE podrías ser una manera, en mis casos lo uso cuando ocupo algo similar a tu caso

Comment: Ya está resuelto, se resuelve con esta misma función, pero cuando vas a agregar una fuente de datos la agregas por medio de una consulta personalizada,